# Caroufredsel interferring with Dropdown menus IE only

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, z-index, caroufredsel

I have been working on a site and have run into an issue in IE where the dropdown does not work as long as I have Caroufredsel running under it...

If you load up the two sites here you can see whats happening:

working in IE7+
http://rjgraphics.com.au/test/amstest
(this is an earlier build prior to putting in caroufred sel)

not working in IE
http://rjgraphics.com.au/test/ams
(the 'products' item should have drop downs)

There seems to be some interference with Caroufredsel and the css which is stopping the menu from dropping down...

How can I resolve the conflict between Caroufredsel and the dropdowns?

Comment: it seems ive figured it out... however there still remains an issue with IE7 8 and above work fine, I've tried z-indexing but we all know z-index in IE7 is aweful :( If anyone knows how to get the z-indexing to work with IE7 then I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a jQuery conflict, so to avoid such problems why are you not using [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html)

Comment: twitter bootstrap requires a lot of customising of the wordpress core in order for it to work... i dont think this is a viable option. thanks for the suggestion though, I really like bootstrap (hadn't seen it before)

Also The menu is pure CSS there is no javascript or jquery being used for the drop downs